# NSString accessing from another class - 0x8ad11a0 does not appear to point to a valid object

Tags: ios, nsstring

I am instantiating a price ticker class, in various other classes. It all worked quite nicely. Now, I have tried to add a property like so:

```
PriceTicker.h

@interface PriceTicker : UIViewController {

NSString *_valueString;

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *valueString;
```

and synthesized it like:

```
PriceTicker.m

@synthesize valueString = _valueString;_
```

The value is then set in various methods below, and yes, the value is indeed set as is verified by console output, etc.

However, when I instantiate PriceTicker in another class, like:

```
totalSavingsTicker = [[PriceTicker alloc] initWithNibName:@"CascadiaTicker" bundle:nil];
```

And then try to set it's value to a local variable, like so:

```
 NSString *savings = [[NSString alloc]init];

savings = totalSavingsTicker.valueString;
```

The value of savings will no set to the value of valueString I see from the log, above.

Comment: Right after `totalSavingsTicker = [[PriceTicker alloc] initWithNibName:@"CascadiaTicker" bundle:nil];`, please log `totalSavingsTicker` to see if it is a valid object.

Comment: Yes it is a valid object. However, when checking valueString I get: (gdb) po [totalSavingsTicker valueString]
Can't print the description of a NIL object.
(gdb) p [totalSavingsTicker valueString]
$2 = (NSString *) 0x0

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this does not answer your question, but this is driving me nuts, so please do not say:

```
NSString *savings = [[NSString alloc]init];
savings = totalSavingsTicker.valueString;
```

All that does is make *two* strings of which the first one is instantly thrown away, which is wasteful and pointless. Say this:

```
NSString *savings;
savings = totalSavingsTicker.valueString;
```

Or even better, this:

```
NSString *savings = totalSavingsTicker.valueString;
```

EDIT: Now that you've described your problem a little better, you are reporting this message from the debugger: "Can't print the description of a NIL object"

This is actually sounds correct to me. Unless you actively do something, all object properties come into existence set to nil. So when you say:

```
totalSavingsTicker = [[PriceTicker alloc] initWithNibName:@"CascadiaTicker" bundle:nil];
NSString *savings = totalSavingsTicker.valueString;
```

I would *expect* `savings` to be nil at that moment, because I would expect the `valueString` property to be nil at that moment. You need to start *working* with this view controller, getting its view into the interface, etc.

Another problem that comes from your subsequent comments is this:

```
[self.savingsView addSubview:totalSavingsTicker.view];
```

That's illegal. You are not allowed to just recklessly add a view controller's view to your interface. You have to use proper parent-child view controller relationships (or else don't use a view controller at all).

Comment: Thanks, I actually had it your way to start. But just started breaking it into more lines to see if my problem was with my NSString not being allocated, for some reason.

Comment: I understand! But surely it is `totalSavingsTicker` we need to be concentrating on.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that totalSavingsTicker is a new instance of PriceTicker, not the one you set the value of valueString in. You need to get a reference to the instance that was on screen where you set that value. I can't tell you how to do that without knowing how your controllers relate to each other.

Comment: The PriceTicker is declared in the interface of client.h like: PriceTicker *totalSavingsTicker;  then in client.m it fills a UIView which acts as it's placeholder, like so: totalSavingsTicker = [[PriceTicker alloc] initWithNibName:@"CascadiaTicker" bundle:nil];
 
self.totalSavingsTickerPlaceholder.hidden = YES;
    [self.savingsView addSubview:totalSavingsTicker.view];

Comment: @Fluffhead, and then what? Do you set the value of valueString through interaction with some UI element in totalSavingsTicker.view? You really shouldn't be adding totalSavingsTicker's view to your view without making it a child view controller anyway.

Comment: Yes, there are various other sliders and inputs in the client view which make computations behind the scenes, then trigger a change in PriceTicker. That in turn changes the value of valueString, as per the log.

Comment: @Fluffhead, without seeing more code, it's hard to tell what you're doing. The problem could be the fact that you've added another controllers view as a subview of client's view without using the proper parent-child relationships.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a massive project of which I am just one piece, so I won't be able to change the overall architecture. And yes, I thought adding ViewControllers like this was problematic, but I inherited this code. So, I suppose I need to get a handle on the Ticker or somehow define the proper parent?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I am answering my own question:

Though though suggestions and critiques people made amy be helpful for the next project and general coding improvment (thanks guys). This problem was solved by simply using:

```
self.valueString
```

rather than

```
_valueString or valueString
```